# how to concatenate a char to a char* in C?

Tags: c, char, concatenation, prepend

How can I prepend `char` c to `char* myChar`? I have `c` has a value of `"A"`, and `myChar` has a value of `"LL"`. How can I prepend `c` to `myChar` to make `"ALL"`?

Comment: is this homework?   The general approach, move everything along one character and then insert your new character at the beginning

Comment: First no, and second thank you

Comment: @Keith: For that to work you need a guarantee that there is at least one byte of usable space at the end of the string, which might work for his application or it might not.

Comment: most c string manipulations assume that there is memory,  like strcat, etc.    or constrains the operation with a 'n'.  memory is usually a issue dealt with outside of the operation

Comment: If we can assume there is memory available before the string, then do:  `*(--myChar) = c;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
#include <string.h>    
char * prepend(const char * str, char c)
{
    char * new_string = malloc(strlen(str)+2);  // add 2 to make room for the character we will prepend and the null termination character at the end
    if (new_string) {
        new_string[0] = c;
        strcpy(new_string + 1, str);
    }
    return new_string;
}
```

Just remember to `free()` the resulting new string when you are done using it, or else you will have a memory leak.

Also, if you are going to be doing this hundreds or thousands of times to the same string, then there are other ways you can do it that will be much more efficient.

Comment: this doesn't prepend to his existing string, it makes a new one,  you could copy it back to str,  but more elegant to do it without mallocing

Comment: Another thing I forgot to mention:  If you're serious about writing good code you should check the return value of malloc to make sure it is not NULL.  If it is NULL then print a proper error message and exit.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first you need to figure out storage for your new string.  If all I know about the source is a `char *`, I don't know whether it points to a buffer that I can overwrite and/or is long enough, or whether I need to allocate a new buffer.

To allocate a new buffer, it'd be something like this:

```
char * strprep(char c, const char * myChar)
{
    /* length, +1 for c, +1 for '\0'-terminator */
    char * newString = malloc(strlen(myChar) + 2);

    /* out-of-memory condition rolls downhill */
    if (newString == NULL) return NULL;

    /* populate the new string */
    newString[0] = c;
    strcpy(newString + 1, myChar);
    return newString;
}
```

To overwrite in place, you'll need to move the characters over to make room for the new start of string:

```
char * strprep(char c, char * myChar)
{
    int len = strlen(myChar);
    int i;

    /* Move over! */
    for (i = len; i >= 0; i--) myChar[i + 1] = myChar[i];

    /* Now plug in the new prefix. */
    myChar[0] = c;
    return c;
}
```

If your C library has it available, you can use `memmove` in place of the loop to shift the original characters up by one.

Comment: You're not allowed to call your function `strprep`, because all names beginning with `str` followed by a letter are reserved for future library use.  `str_prepend` would be fine, though.

Answer (score -1):

Probably not the most efficient but this is a step in the right direction: this one is clearly direct approach -

```
  int main()
   {
      int i;
      char tempc;
      for (i=0; i<strlen(str); i++)
      {
        tempc = c;
        c = str[i];
        str[i] = tempc;            
         str[i+1] = c;
      }
       *(str[i+1]) = malloc(1);
       str[i+1] = '\0';
    }
```